# Scroll down from current position

Tags: javascript

So i have this svg map, i have named all streeds and jump to the streets location on screen just bu putting the #streetname behind url. All pretty straight forward.

However this puts the searched street at the top-left of the screen. So i searched some solutions and found the following:

```
function scrolldown() {
     document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop  - 100;
     document.documentElement.scrollLeft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft  + 170;
 }
```

This however brings two problems to the table:

1. its not responsive, i basically want it to scroll down and to the left half of the screen width, so when the screen shrinks it needs to scroll less down and to the left.
2. I have put this map in an iframe on another page, the above method scrolls down the map inside the iframe but allso the entire streen of the page which the iframe is placed in. i tried replacing the document. with the following to no result.

   ```
   function scrolldown() {
    var elmnt = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
    var ypos = elmnt.documentElement.scrollTop / 2;
    var xpos = elmnt.documentElement.scrollLeft / 2;
    elmnt.documentElement.scrollTop = elmnt.documentElement.scrollTop  - ypos;
    elmnt.documentElement.scrollLeft = elmnt.documentElement.scrollLeft  - xpos;}
   ```

The above code just does nothing

My basic html layout is as following

```
<head>
<body onload="scrolldown()" />
</head>
<body>
<svg>

</svg>
<script>
function scrolldown() {
 var elmnt = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
 var ypos = elmnt.documentElement.scrollTop / 2;
 var xpos = elmnt.documentElement.scrollLeft / 2;
 elmnt.documentElement.scrollTop = elmnt.documentElement.scrollTop  - ypos;
 elmnt.documentElement.scrollLeft = elmnt.documentElement.scrollLeft  - xpos;}
</script>
</body>
```

This html page is loaded into the main page using an iframe

```
<iframe src="map.php">
```

[full code here](https://codepen.io/Mika_vd_wiel/pen/XWrzzXw)

The solution is probably verry straight foreward however i am not the best with javascript.

Comment: If you want to scroll the content document of an iframe, you'll need to access `elmnt.contentDocument.documentElement.scrollTop`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol , i don't want to scroll the iframe from the parrent page, i want to scroll the iframe from within the iframe and it to only effect that iframe